# Visible/hidden content affecting loading speed of page? How to retrieve external data on demand?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, hidden, page-load-time

**Example**: A list of linked `<H4>` (`<a><H4>maximum 200 characters</H4></a>`) and their corresponding divs (`<div>maximum 10000 characters</div>`) are simultaneously fetched from a spreadsheet; when any one of those visible linked `<H4>` is clicked ( `toggle()` ), their corresponding prior hidden divs ( `hide()` ) gets displayed. The list of linked `<H4>` and related divs grows as the spreadsheet grows, like a Comments form.

Questions:

1. Does the **`<H4>` list** load faster (or appear faster on the page)
   when the divs are hidden beforehand (`hide()`)?
2. If question 1 is negatif, what would be the simplest jQuery function structure, in this example, to retrieve and display the divs after the linked `<H4>`s are loaded and only upon User `<H4>` click? I already have the data-fetching function figured out (google.jsapi) so I would need the correct jQuery function structure allowing User on-demand loading of supplementary data. Any pointers?

**Note**: Currently developing on jQuery 1.6+ . Code above is simplified for description only. The reason why the `<H4>`s are wrapped within `<a>` tags is a cross-browser issue and to allow accessibilty with accesskeys and Tab for keyboard Users (I tried the `each()` method for clickable `H4`s and Firefox did not let me down however IE 6-7 hated me for that and froze).

Comment: Why fetch from spread sheet? Just curious

Comment: @Emmanuel N : I am building a Google gadget which interacts with Google spreadsheets. The gadget functions on Google Sites pages. The spreadsheet is used to gather input from Google Forms which will be moderated before publishing on a Google Sites page. If there are other means to collect Form input displayable and publishable on Google Sites pages without spreadsheet usage do remind me - I am a newbie but fast learner and want to delve deeper into customizable Forms UI and data manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

1) Does the  list load faster (or appear faster on the page) when the divs are hidden beforehand (hide())?

Answer:

As long as you are loading hidden divs the same time you are loading your page, your page won't load faster/signifcantly faster

2) If question 1 is negatif, what would be the simplest jQuery function structure, in this example, to retrieve and display the divs after the linked s are loaded and only upon User  click?

Answer:

Use ajax to populate divs on demand, create a page with empty hidden div, and load those div using ajax request when you are showing them. All this can be done using javascript/JQuery

Comment: Ok, I gathered some Ajax sprinkling would be helpful, I will try to blend it with the existing code and see what gives - thx for reminding me.